# Form action based on Input Type selection

Tags: php, html, forms

I am creating a form in php on the page "index.php". When the page is loaded the following form is created:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']!='POST')
{
        echo '
        <form action="index.php" method="POST">
        <fieldset style="width: 700px;">
        <legend>Enter your search below</legend>
        <textarea rows="1" cols="80" name="query">
        </textarea>
        </fieldset>
        <p>
        <input type="radio" value="Non-Aggregated"> Non-Aggregated
        <input type="radio" value="Aggregated"> Aggregated 
        &nbsp;
        &nbsp;
        <input type="submit" value="Search">
        </p>
        </form>';   
}
```

When the user clicks the submit button, the appropriate content is displayed:

```
else
{
    if ($_POST['query'])
    {
        //content displayed after form submission
    }
}
```

Going back to the form, note the radio options:

```
<input type="radio" value="Non-Aggregated"> Non-Aggregated
<input type="radio" value="Aggregated"> Aggregated
```

Is there a condition that I can place in the if-statement to carry out a different action based on whether ***Non-Aggregated*** or ***Aggregated*** is selected from the radio buttons; and if so how would I go about doing this?

Thanks for any help at all.

Comment: you can change it with javascript but what do you want to do at all?

Comment: @AndreasLinden if the user selects Non-Aggregated I will display certain information, if they select Aggregated I will display other information.

Comment: well so do a switch in on the post-field in php, don't change the html... see my upcomming answer

Comment: Hi, sorry I made a small but vital edit, the else statement should have read `if ($_POST['query'])` not `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']!='POST')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give name attribute to radio buttons, like

```
<input type="radio" name="aggr" value="Non-Aggregated"> Non-Aggregated
<input type="radio" name="aggr" value="Aggregated"> Aggregated
```

After POST method is executed you can check values with PHP:

```
if($_POST['aggr']=='Aggregated'){
//DO STUFF
}
if($_POST['aggr']=='Non-Aggregated'){
//DO OTHER STUFF
}
```

In other way, you can set names, like

```
<input type="radio" name="Non-Aggregated" value="Non-Aggregated"> Non-Aggregated
<input type="radio" name="Aggregated" value="Aggregated"> Aggregated
```

And check this if `isset`

```
if(isset($_POST['Aggregated'])){
    //DO STUFF
}
if(isset($_POST['Non-Aggregated'])){
  //DO OTHER STUFF
}
```

Comment: Thanks @FOG, I have tested your first way and it works. Other answers seem to do similar stuff, so thank you everybody :)

Answer (score 4):

First of all, asign a "name" to your radios. Same to both.

```
<input type="radio" name="aggregation" value="Non-Aggregated"> Non-Aggregated
<input type="radio" name="aggregation" value="Aggregated"> Aggregated
```

On the "else" clause, make a small change, insted of

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']!='POST')
```

use

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST')
```

And last, but not least, add your condition inside that last if...

```
if ($_POST['aggregation'] == 'Aggregated')
{
// Actions for Aggregated
}
else
{
// Actions for Non-Aggregated
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']!='POST')
{
    // echo the form and don't forget to give the radio inputs a name
    // <input name="agg" type="radio" value="Non-Aggregated"> Non-Aggregated
    // <input name="agg" type="radio" value="Aggregated"> Aggregated 
}
else if (isset($_POST['agg']))
{
    if ($_POST['agg'] == 'Aggregated') {
        // do one thing
    } else {
        // do something else
    }
}
```

Comment: I would modify the conditional to `if(isset($_POST['agg']) && $_POST['aggr'] == 'Aggregated')` for a piece of mind

Comment: just added it to the outer condition as if it's not set at all you  don't want to perform the action for "not-aggregated"

Answer (score 3):

Here is working code:

```
<?php if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']!='POST')
{
    $form = <<<FORM
<form action="" method="POST">
<fieldset style="width: 700px;">
<legend>Enter your search below</legend>
<textarea rows="1" cols="80" name="query">
</textarea>
</fieldset>
<p>
<input type="radio" value="Non-Aggregated" name='radioCheck'> Non-Aggregated
<input type="radio" value="Aggregated" name='radioCheck'> Aggregated 
&nbsp;
&nbsp;
<input type="submit" value="Search">
</p>
</form>
FORM;
echo $form;
}
elseif($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset($_POST['radioCheck']) && $_POST['radioCheck'] =='Non-Aggregated'){

// Non-Aggregated form
    echo 'Non-Aggregated';

}elseif($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset($_POST['radioCheck']) && $_POST['radioCheck'] =='Aggregated'){
// Aggregated form

    echo 'Aggregated';
}
?>
```