# Submit Form to action based on Selection

Tags: php, jquery

I have a list of records in a table with a checkbox beside each one.

The user selects a number of records by ticking the checkbox and then selects an action from a drop down list of links.

```
<div class="button-group">
    <button type="button" id="but1">Action</button>
    <ul class="dropdown" id="dropdown-but1">
        <li><a href="#">Update Attendees</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">One more action</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

An example of an action might be updating if a user attend an event.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    foreach ($_POST['checkbox_mark'] as $value => $dummy) {
        $option = isset($_POST['checkbox'][$value]) ? '1' : '0';
        // Send the Data to the Model
        $eventRegistrationModel->markAttended($value, $id, $option);
    } 

}
```

At the minute I have this working for a single submit button, but I would like the user to be able to choose from a list of options in a dropdown and then the appropriate action is called.

I can't seem to find an example of this, but I am maybe not searching for the correct term.
Assuming I will need to use jquery for this.

I have found a way to do this using the form elements https://stackoverflow.com/a/17423522/1472203
but wondering if it is possible with text links.

Comment: Text links or a dropdown? They're different

Comment: It's text links I want.

Comment: Is that an aesthetic choice or functional?

Comment: Hadn't thought of it that way. I suppose for aesthetics, but I could just style the select element the same way.

Comment: Okay, check my answer :) I was wondering why you're not using a `select`?

Comment: yep that was what I had originally. Just need to style the button to look like a link instead. Or else I could use the select element.

Comment: Seems like the best way to do it. You could also use a `<select>` and then use javascript to detect which option is selected, and upated the `action` of the `<form>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Making submit buttons look like links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367409/how-to-make-button-look-like-a-link)

Then have as many different submit buttons as you'd like for each action and in the action file just check for the submission of the buttons:

```
<div class="button-group">
    <button type="button" id="but1">Action</button>
    <ul class="dropdown" id="dropdown-but1">
        <li><input type="submit" name="update_attendees" value="Update Attendees" class="buttonThatLooksLikeALink"></li>
        <li><input type="submit" name="another_action" value="Another action" class="buttonThatLooksLikeALink"></li>
        <li><input type="submit" name="one_more_action" value="One more action" class="buttonThatLooksLikeALink"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Then in PHP:

```
<?php

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]==="POST")
{
    if(isset($_POST["update_attendees"]))
    {
        # Update those attendees!
    }
    elseif(isset($_POST["another_action"]))
    {
        # Do that other action!
    }
    elseif(isset($_POST["one_more_action"]))
    {
        # Do the OTHER action
    }
}
```